# How to find a limit for sup cos?

Tags: limits

could somebody tell me how to find the limit for:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}$ sup cos $\frac{\pi \cdot n}{4}$

I would say this sequence doesnt converge because only the numerator increases

havent seen this notation with sup cos

Comment: Can you find an $n$ such that the $\cos$ is 1? Can you find an $n'>n$ such that $\cos=1$ as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is supposed to be $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\cos\frac{\pi n}4,$$ which can instead be rewritten as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sup_{k\ge n}\left(\cos\frac{\pi k}4\right)\right].$$ Regardless of our choice of $n,$ what is $$\sup_{k\ge n}\left(\cos\frac{\pi k}4\right)?$$ What can we then conclude?

---

**Added**: The notation $$\sup_{k\ge n}\left(\cos\frac{\pi k}4\right)$$ is shorthand for $$\sup\left\{\cos\frac{\pi k}4: k\ge n\right\},$$ where $k$ is assumed to be an integer. Due to the fact that the cosine function has period $2\pi=\frac{8\pi}4,$ we can see that for any integer $n,$ we have $$\left\{\cos\frac{\pi k}4: k\ge n\right\}=\left\{\cos\frac{\pi k}4: n\le k\le n+7\right\}.$$ Furthermore--again regardless of our choice of integer $n$--there is exactly one integer $k$ such that $n\le k\le n+7$ and such that $8$ is a factor of $k,$ meaning in particular that $\frac{\pi k}4k$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi,$ so that $\cos\frac{\pi k}4=1.$ Since $1$ is the greatest possible value of $\cos x$ for real $x,$ then for all integers $n$ we have $$\sup_{k\ge n}\cos\frac{\pi k}4=\sup\left\{\cos\frac{\pi k}4: k\ge n\right\}=\sup\left\{\cos\frac{\pi k}4: n\le k\le n+7\right\}=1,$$ and so $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\cos\frac{\pi n}4=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sup_{k\ge n}\left(\cos\frac{\pi k}4\right)\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}[1]=1.$$

---

**Side Note**: Suppose we are given any sequence of real numbers $a_n.$ Then we define and denote the *limit superior* and *limit inferior* of the sequence by $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sup_{k\ge n}a_k\right]$$ and $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\inf_{k\ge n}a_k\right],$$ respectively. Here are a few nice results (and nice exercises to prove) about these special limits:

- The sequences $$\left\{\sup_{k\ge n} a_k\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$$ and $$\left\{\inf_{k\ge n} a_k\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$$ are non-increasing and non-decreasing, respectively. Hence, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$$ exists if and only if $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded below, and $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n$$ exists if and only if $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded above.
- If both $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exist, then $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\ge\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n.$
- If $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, then both $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exist, and in particular, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n.$$
- If both $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exist, and if $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n,$ then $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n.$$

Comment: its a line with no convergence?

Comment: Bear in mind that the cosine function is periodic with period $2\pi,$ and that the cosine of a real number must lie in the interval $[-1,1].$ If you're still not sure, try finding the first bunch of values of $\cos\frac{\pi k}4,$ until you spot the pattern.

Comment: it is bounded  but it doesnt converge therefore there is no limit

Comment: is it correct?.

Comment: or maybe $1$...i just don know

Comment: maybe some one can explain...

Comment: It's true that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\cos\frac{\pi k}4\right)$$ does not exist, but that isn't what the question is about. Again, I ask, what is $$\sup_{k\ge n}\left(\cos\frac{\pi k}4\right)?$$

Comment: sorry i do not know

Comment: Bingo! I just finished updating my answer, which now also includes some more general information about limits superior and inferior, and how they are related to boundedness and convergence of real sequences.

Comment: You are very welcome. Just so you're aware, after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). You can only accept one answer per question, and you don't have to accept right away (or at all), but it's a good practice.